# Starting a manually created service that is configured to run a command

Tags: windows, service, cmd

I am testing a cisco anyconnect exploit PoC and I created a service for testing that creates a folder in the C drive:

```
sc create Inter binPath= "cmd.exe /c mkdir C:\TEST"
```

I know this can be done in other ways like scheduled tasks or startup scripts but I need it to be a service.

The service shows up in services.msc however, whenever I try to start it I get an "error 1053 service failed to start in a timely fashion" error.

I did some research and there was a problem with the .net framework for managing the services some time ago but I have .net 4.5 installed so that is not the problem. Furthermore I found some resources that suggested I should increase the timeout from the default of 30 seconds to 2 minutes. However creating a folder is almost instant so this shouldn't be the problem either. This service is not interactive as the default type is set to 0x10 by default (WIN32_OWN_PROCESS)

I tried it on windows 7 32 and 64 bit and windows 8.1 64 bit.

Does anyone know how to debug the problem or what the problem really is?

Comment: maybe helpfull : http://serverfault.com/questions/54676/how-to-create-a-service-running-a-bat-file-on-windows-2008-server

Comment: You can't just take any old executable and pretend that it's a service.  You need to use srvany.exe (from MS) or the third-party NSSM.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Solved by coding a service in Visual Studio. Thanks! People trying this could find these videos useful: https://youtu.be/uM9o8GsO_u4